# How to find out seasonality in Time Series Data without looking at the graph?

Tags: r, time-series, python, seasonality

I've a data which has multiple time series. I want to find the seasonality in the data based on a number as it won't be feasible to check the seasonality by checking the plot. There are around 2505 time series.

I explored, but was unable to find any good solution/ approach?

Can any expert help me out with this!

Comment: You youd check the autocorrelation in lag 12

Comment: You should read here: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscharacteristics/

Comment: `stl() function`: https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/timeseries.html